# Executing PyQGIS scripts from .bat file to control open instance of QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-python-console, bat

I'm trying to run PyQGIS scripts via a 3rd party program, to perform actions to layers inside an open QGIS instance. I'm able to have the outside program shell and execute a bat file to run them.

I'm stuck trying to get them to work with my open instance of QGIS.
Is there some way to run them just as they would run from within the Python Console in QGIS without needing a bunch of imports and setup? Restated, if it works within the Python Console can I somehow launch it externally without changing anything? I could get lost for a very long time otherwise trying to set this up right.

Example of what I've tried:

```py
import qgis.utils
from qgis.utils import iface

print(iface.activeLayer().name)
```

result in error:

> "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'activeLayer'"

Example:

```py
from qgis.core import *

prg = QgsProject.instance()
layer = prg.mapLayersByName("open_layer")[0]
```

result in error:

> "IndexError: list index out of range"